# How to rename a txt file with a Spanish letter with batch

Tags: batch-file

I have this script, and I found here these codes 
but I am a bit confused on how to intergrade them to the script 
and I found a link to a website to many other codes

```
@echo off
Setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
cd /d "%~dp0"
Set "Pattern=Coupé"
Set "Replace=Coupe"

FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('dir /b /s /a-d "*.txt"') DO (
    Set "File=%%~na"
    Ren "%%a" "!File:%Pattern%=%Replace%!%%~xa"
```

How do I place these code in my script

```
CHCP 852   > NUL
CHCP 1250  > NUL
CHCP 1252  > NUL
CHCP 1145  > NUL    
CHCP 20284 > NUL
```

I am also working on a script to rename folders 
is it possible to edit my script to rename folders

I have other scripts for renaming folders, but I am really interested on converting the script above to renaming folders >br>

```
@For /F "EOL=? Delims=" %%G In ('Dir /B /S /A:D') Do @PushD "%%G" && (ren "Coupé" "Coupe" CHCP 20284 > NUL 2>&1 & PopD)
```

Not sure if I added it correctly in this script

Any help with this will be super because I literally have many folders and files with Spanish characters and they are all scattered so it's very hard to fined them all

I'm sorry I did not share my attempts, but since I have no idea where to place them I have nothing in attempts

Thank you

Comment: You have to add the right `chcp` before you are renaming the text files.

Comment: It's very simple. Just make sure that you save your batch file, as ANSI text with the same codepage you're using, e.g. [Example](https://ibb.co/VN16PSN), from the text editor I have open currently. I would advise generally that it is saved as codepage 1252, but the choice is yours. Then begin your script using the following code, substituting `1252` as needed: ```@%SystemRoot%\System32\chcp.com 1252 1>NUL```.

Comment: @Compo - with my current script how do I go about making it edit folders, right now it edits files with matching patterns

Comment: Open a Command Prompt window, type `dir /?` and press the `[ENTER]` key. You should clearly see which options you've used, and which ones are available. Pay particular attention to the parameters for the `/A` option.

Comment: @compo Thank you I got it going, it can now rename folders `: )`